# Transfer tool for unmanaged users GCP

Tags: google-workspace

Is there any way to export the list of consumer accounts from the google cloud admin console ( Transfer tool for unmanaged users) . Or I have to do copy/paste .
I was looking for a way to get : user email // Request Status // Last sent // Request already sent.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to export all the accounts in the project you can do the following:

```sh
gcloud projects get-iam-policy PROJECT-ID
```

To get all the accounts:

```sh
gcloud projects get-iam-policy PROJECT_ID | awk -F ":" '{print $2}' | grep '@'
```

To get the ones that are not service accounts (not managed):

```sh
gcloud projects get-iam-policy PROJECT_ID | awk -F ":" '{print $2}' | grep '@' |  grep --invert-match "serviceaccount.com"
```

Answer (score 0):

There's no API for the [transfer tool for unmanaged users](https://support.google.com/a/answer/6178640), and there's no option to export the list from the UI.